# Audit website my pages have HTTPS URL links to an HTTP URL

Tags: wordpress, security, audit

I have an wordpress website https://tricourilemele.ro . When doing an audit, my Security Score is showing an high issue: HTTPS URL links to an HTTP URL..

Looking at page source (in fact on all pages) i find these http://gmpg.org/xfn/11 and anther link - which in is in fact a page i made http://tricourilemele.ro/tricouri-personalizate/

Well... i found that  http://gmpg.org/xfn/11 in my header is given by my theme - Storefront, even so it had many updates, they never changed that to https.

I tried with a plugin search / replace but i couldn't do any improves .more. i was afraid to try something else. I do not know many related to databases or so..

My problem is ...How could i change those 2 links from http to https?
Please, be

Thank you,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find whatever file gmpg is in, and update the url to https. And then change the url accordingly for the site you created.

Comment: Thank you Tee...My problem is not to know how to update all my pages where this is present ....and i have maore than 400 pages witth this issue...

Comment: Solved ..I changed the url in the theme's header..Thank you! Marius